# How can I resolve a name clash between a defined function and a parameter in another function?

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to resolve a name clash. Here's the gist of what I've got in front of me:

```
def clean():
    # do some cleaning stuff

def build(clean=True):
    if clean:
        clean()
```

Oops.

For a few reasons, I do not want to change the API here. What is the best strategy to resolve this conflict? For now, I'm doing:

```
def clean():
    # do some cleaning stuff
clean_alias = clean

def build(clean=True):
    if clean:
        clean_alias()
```

Which might be the best/only solution short of renaming things. I'm just wondering if there's a different way to reference the `clean` that's in the outer scope from within the body of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
globals()['clean']()
```

> globals()
>
> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol
>   table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a
>   function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the
>   module from which it is called).

Comment: Great answer. I ended up doing `clean_func = globals()['clean']` at the top of the function definition for clarity's sake. FYI I will mark this as answered tomorrow, it won't let me mark it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a default argument, that binds the global `clean` function to a local variable.

```
def build(clean=True, cleanFn=clean): 
    if clean: 
        cleanFn()
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I ended up going with the answer @Kos gave because his solution doesn't add extraneous noise in the function signature.